# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:Requested Tensor connection between nodes "input_1" and "input_1" would create a cycle

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I work with keras and deep learning in python.
My network is an autoencoder That's inside a CNN 1D

Part of my code is:

```
history = autoencoder.fit(input_img,input_img,
                                 epochs= 100,
                                 steps_per_epoch=64,
                                 validation_steps=1,
                                 validation_split = 0.1 ,
                                 verbose=1,                              
                                 shuffle=True,                                    
                                 validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
                                 callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')]
                          )
```

I obtained the following error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:Requested 
Tensor connection between nodes "input_1" and "input_1" would create a cycle
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet where you build the autoencoder network?